Vite PWA assets generator - How to manage multiple SVG
I'm trying to use the Vite PWA's assets generator to create my images for favicons & PWA icons.
I have 2 SVG versions of my logo, 2 different versions, one for the small icons and one for the bigger icons.
pwa-assets.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from '@vite-pwa/assets-generator/config'

export default defineConfig({
    preset: {
        transparent: {
            sizes: [64, 192, 512],
            favicons: [[48, 'favicon.ico']],
            padding: 0
        },
        maskable: {
            sizes: [512],
            padding: 0
        },
        apple: {
            sizes: [180],
            padding: 0,
        }
    },
    images: [
        'public/img/logo-sm.svg',
        'public/img/logo-lg.svg'
    ]
})

Is there a way to choose which version to use for which target ?
ie. the logo-sm for the 48px favicon and logo-lg for the 512px targets
